# How would I clear all rails sessions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

Here is my code:

```
if session[:firsttimestart].nil? 
else
  @firsttime = false
end

if @firsttime == true
  initglobals()
end
session[:firsttimestart]=false
```

The problem is when I turn off the server and come back to the application, the  session[:firsttimestart] is still false. It somehow stores this variable in my system without an expiration date so the iniglobals() is not called. I tried to use rake tmp:clear and it didn't work. How can I clear all the sessions that am using in my system each time I restart my server?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you are storing your sessions in a db then

```
rake db:sessions:clear
```

Comment: Although, this may not shrunk your DB disk space. In postgres, I need to run the following after clearing sessions: `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE;` and `REINDEX table sessions;`. In other relational dbs, you may need to optimize it as well.

Comment: See @Yevgeniy's answer below

Comment: If you're not using DB to store sessions, on Rails 3, then you just need to change your app's secret token and all sessions will be reset. To do this, run `rake secret` on the command line to generate a new secret and then copy/paste it into your config/initializers/secret_token.rb file.

Answer (score 50):

Whether it's DB or cookie store, use `rake tmp:sessions:clear`

Comment: Obviously can't work for cookie store because sessions are kept client side.

Comment: @dolzenko only a session_id is stored on the client side. All the session data is stored server side. So there shouldnt be any reason you cant clear the cookie sessions from server side.

Comment: @Nick this is only true for DB session store, cookie store stores everything client side, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-storage and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore.html for details

Comment: Ah I didn't know rails used this rather unconventional strategy but it does indeed look like you're correct.

Comment: This saved me after giving up.

Answer (score 7):

In Rails 4, the accepted answer (`rake db:sessions:clear`) no longer works because ActiveRecord::SessionStore was extracted into the `active_record-session_store` gem. (See [here](http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/activerecord-sessionstore-gem-extraction-rails-4-countdown-to-2013) for further explanation)

You can now either install the `active_record-session_store` gem and use `rake db:sessions:clear` as in Rails 3, or create a custom Rake task that looks like so:

```
namespace :db do
    namespace :sessions do
        desc "Clear ActiveRecord sessions"
        task :clear => :environment do
            sql = 'TRUNCATE sessions;'
            ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

In Rails 5 if using ActiveRecord:

`ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.delete_all`

or for more granular:

```
# For example schedule this once a day`
ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.where(["updated_at < ?", 2.weeks.ago]).delete_all
```

Comment: I tried this in console and it gave me error of NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::SessionStore. Any Idea why this is not working.

Comment: you can just use "Session" instead of "ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session"

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, nil is not == false, however, nil evaluates to false. Try it yourself if you do not believe:

```
irb(main):001:0> nil == false
=> false
irb(main):002:0> nil == nil
=> true
```

Which ofcourse means:

```
irb(main):003:0> false.nil?
=> false
```

You can clean up your code in the following manner as it seems like @firsttime is never set to true anywhere.

```
unless session[:visited]
  session[:visited] = true
  initglobals
end
```

Finally, rake tmp:sessions:clear will only work if you are using ActiveRecordStore, if you are using CookieStore (which is the default). Then you will need to clean your cookies, or use reset_session.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Rails 4 and the following solution worked for me as I do not want to manual run `rake db:session:clear` every time I start my application.

Inside /config/initializer/session_store.rb add the following

```
ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.delete_all
```

This is just the same as the rake command but done at the initializer level.

Answer (score 2):

Best is to change the secret key on the deployment, all cookies will be invalidated

technically, you should be providing one already via an environment variable.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#custom-secrets

for the rake task, it looks like the new one is

```
rails tmp:clear
```

Answer (score 1):

At least for **sessions stored in cookies**, you could just change your session store key:

initializers/session_store.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_my_new_session_key'
```

According to the Rails API: *...changing your secret_key_base will invalidate all existing sessions*

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore.html

Answer (score 0):

To present an alternative solution: you could change the `secret_key_base` - if the authentication is done in another application.

Answer (score 0):

```
rake db:schema:cache:clear
```

this clears cache and all sessions when using rails API, and for other databse tasks use:

```
rake --tasks
```