# how to clear all user sessions in a RoR app in start up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

Any one know how to clear/null all user sessions in a RoR app during app start up?

Thanks in advance.

Raf

Comment: See [How would I clear all rails sessions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074292/how-would-i-clear-all-rails-sessions)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using :active_record_store you can drop the sessions table or just point to a new table by configuring this

```
ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.table_name = 'legacy_session_table'
```

If you are using file store, you need to clear the file.