# Rails temporary session cookies & db reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, session-cookies, railstutorial.org

I'm working through the Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial, and there's a section where he has you seed the development database with fake users. The first step in this process is running `rails db:migrate:reset` and then you run `db:seed`.

When I ran these commands, I happened to be logged in to the app in the browser.
I therefore still had a temporary session cookie (set via `session[:user_id] = user.id`) stored in my browser. The ID of my user was 3.

As a consequence of this, I found that upon seeding the database, I could refresh the browser and be logged in as the new user whose ID is now 3.

Related to this: logging out of the application deletes the session cookie (via `session.delete(:user_id)`). But I found that if you were to (1) copy the cookie when you are logged in, (2) log out and close the browser, and (3) reuse the copied cookie (either in the same browser, or another machine/browser), you would still be automatically authenticated and logged in, without needing user/pass. Is there a standard way to prevent a particular cookie from being used again after logout?

Both of these cases work because the first conditional in this `current_user` method passes and assigns the ID # to `user_id`:

```
# Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
def current_user
  if (user_id = session[:user_id])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
  elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
    user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
    if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
      log_in user
      @current_user = user
    end
  end
end
```

Perhaps both of these scenarios are very rare cases. In the first case, I imagine reseting the database of a production application is very undesirable, as would be any reassignment of record IDs. Still, I'm wondering how concerning this situation is and what measures are typically implemented to avoid it. Many thanks!

Comment: Don't be afraid to upvote questions you find useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074292/how-would-i-clear-all-rails-sessions), if you are using file based sessions, you can clear all of your Rails sessions using:

```
bundle exec rake tmp:sessions:clear
```

If you are using database sessions you can run this to clear all sessions:

```
bundle exec rake db:sessions:clear
```

You could also invalidate sessions be changing the `secret_key_base` in `config/secrets.yml`.

This should clear all of the sessions for all of the users.  It will log every user out and invalidate their sessions, but it is the most secure way of ensuring old cookies cannot access user data after you migrate your database.

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me. I got the following traceback:

`Don't know how to build task 'tmp:sessions:clear' (see --tasks)1`
I also checked and there's no `sessions` dir within `tmp`. Maybe it's just the case that this tutorial does not make use of that? The answer you linked to that recommends `rake tmp:sessions:clear` has some responses that suggest that this doesn't work when all the data is stored client side. So I can infer that one _ought_ to store it server side. Is there a standard way to implement that with Rails? `session[:key] = value` seems to default to client side.

Comment: You may be using database sessions.  I expanded the answer to include clearing database sessions and changing the secret key base.  One or both of those should work.

Comment: @tom-arnarda Yep that works (changing `secret_key_base` in `config/secrets.yml`). Thanks a lot. So I guess the thing to do is to change this key whenever you migrate the database? Or at least in the case where something like the User.id is stored in a client session. For an individual user logging out, however, is there a way to prevent their logged-in session cookie from being reused? I guess you would need to keep a record of all in-use sessions?

Comment: There are ways, but that belongs in a separate question.  :)